# java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching <name> found

Tags: scala, ssl, https, playframework, certificate

I am using play framework, and I am using WSClient to perform an API call to an external API.
I am getting the below error

```html
java.net.ConnectException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching <name> found.
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:162)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener$1.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:133)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleFutureListener.java:26)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:514)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:486)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:427)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:129)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.notifyHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1238)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1233)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1208)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1063)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:902)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching <name> found.
```

However, this call is returning valid data from Postman or the browser

Comment: `<name>` is wrong ...

Comment: <name> is the hostname, I just hid the hostname and replaced it with <name>

Comment: I know. Just saying, this error means your hostname is wrong.